# Adding Fixed sidebar to webpage

Tags: html, css

My target is the fixed side menu like this on this website:
http://www.elated.com/

This is my HTML code:

```
    <!-- Scroll TEST -->
<ul id="followTab">
    <li>
        <a class="newsletter" href="newsletter/" title="Subscribe to ...">
          <span> Subscribe to ...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="twitter" href="newsletter/" title="Subscribe to ...">
          <span> Subscribe to ...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

and this is my CSS style

```
    /* Follow tab */

#followTab {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  right: 0;
  top: 130px;
  width: 24px;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background: rgba(239, 91, 10, .75);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 52, 8, .75), rgba(239, 91, 10, .75));
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from( rgba(243, 52, 8, .75) ), to( rgba(239, 91, 10, .75) ) );
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 52, 8, .75), rgba(239, 91, 10, .75));
}

#followTab li {
  margin: 9px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

#followTab li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#followTab a {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  background-image: url("/css/images/follow-tab-buttons.png");
}

#followTab a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
}

#followTab a.newsletter {
  height: 16px;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#followTab a.newsletter:hover {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}

#followTab a.rss {
  background-position: 0 -32px;
  height: 24px;
}

#followTab a.rss:hover {
  background-position: 0 -56px;
}

#followTab a.twitter {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  height: 15px;
}

#followTab a.twitter:hover {
  background-position: 0 -95px;
}

#followTab a.facebook {
  background-position: 0 -110px;
  height: 24px;
}

#followTab a.facebook:hover {
  background-position: 0 -134px;
}
```

For some reason I am not getting the images to show. Hoping to get some pointers.
Live website can be [found here](http://www.aroundgalaxy.pt/NEW)

Comment: It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/CaUB5/

Comment: what about the images?

Comment: You have asked no question about images in your OP.

Comment: well since i asked to have something like... (that has images) i think i did.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're expecting; like others say, the link to the website seems to look ok. Perhaps edit your question to make it more explicit what you want?

Comment: edited, my issue is not having the images/icons to show at all.

Comment: To further clarify, those images/icons are supposed to be in the on the right-hand side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the path to your images.

Currently you have: `/css/images/follow-tab-buttons.png` which is an absolute reference, so it starts at the root of your site.

But your site is located at `/NEW/`

Either: add `/NEW` before the image URL (`/NEW/css/images/follow-tab-buttons.png`) [Not Recommended]

Or remove the leading `/css/` to make the URL relative (remember, it needs to be relative to your CSS file) - resulting in `images/follow-tab-buttons.png`

Comment: as a follow up, do you have any idea why the code is working on my local machine, but when i upload the content it breaks (returning to not show the images)?

Comment: Most likely the paths are different on your local machine vs. published location.  I'd make sure the folder structure on the server is the same as on your local machine.  Also, make sure you uploaded the images.

Comment: Yes, everything was correctly pathed, i changed the path on the style.css, i think it was browser cache screwing up hours of my work. even after clearing cache and shift+f5 and inspecting the element it always refered to the old incorrectly pathed css. managed to get it working by changing the folder name from "NEW" to "new" to force browser to compile a new cache on that mather.